# throw null in decompiled ArraySegment

Tags: .net, .net-core

I've just had a look at the `ArraySegment` class in .NET Core (`...\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Runtime.dll`).

Every method\property just has `throw null` in it:

```
public T[] Array
{
  get
  {
    throw null;
  }
}
```

What's this for?  How does it work?

Comment: Reference assemblies do not contain code, everything is stubbed-out.  The compiler only uses the declarations in the metadata.  Pick the runtime assembly instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at the *reference assemblies*. That's not the real implementation - it's just a placeholder to compile against, effectively.

You'll see the assembly only has the public/protected members, and every code-based member (property, constructor, method etc) is implemented like this.

The point is to create an assembly which is as small as it can be, but which the compiler can use as a reference. At execution time, the *real* code is present instead.

Comment: OK, That makes sense.  Where does the implementation live then?  Where does the jitter (?) find it?

Comment: @BanksySan: You could look in C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0 for example. But if you're trying to find the source code, I'd look on github instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the implementation.  Just because of curiosity.